# Why TYPE_TABLE isMSShipped?

Tags: sql-server

When I run this query on my database

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sys.objects
 WHERE objectproperty(object_id,'IsMSShipped') = 1
```

I found the result is not only about system objects like system_table, it also contains TT(TYPE_TABLE). I am confused how come these type_tables are shipped with the installation of sql-server? Why they are system objects?

Thanks for anyone who would like to help in advance!

Comment: They aren't system objects. Those would be found in sys.system_objects. Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It states that is_ms_shipped means "Object is created by an internal SQL Server component."

Comment: @SeanLange, thanks for the clarification.